# Extracting a bib file

Tags: bibtex

How to extract a  bib file on a CentOS 
with no bib commands, other than bibtex and pdflatex?
(and I do not have installation rights.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I don't understand your question I think, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Extract from what? do you mean use the information in the `.aux` to extract from the "main" bibliography a new `.bib` file? If so, then you need more than just the commands `bibtex` and `*latex`. If you had `biber`, then it's a breeze; otherwise you want to use something like `bibtool`; or you want to create a program yourself that does what they already do....